# Detect common file paths for resources directory in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, lint, r.java-file

I have 2 packages, package1 and package2 in android. Both the packages have resources directory containing a file with the same name and path i.e both the packages contain /main/res/anim/slide_in_right.xml. I want to have some kind of check to detect such files and throw a warning/error at compilation time.

Similar issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36975476

I tried searching for this problem over android related pages, but only came across ['resourcePrefix' solution](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36975476). This forces the user to add a prefix to their resource files so that we don't face this issue of clash in filenames. But this requires manually going and adding prefix at all places. Styleable attributes are also being matched and erroring out. We do not want our styleable attributes, nor the styleable itself to be forced to use these prefixes.

Comment: "I have 2 packages, package1 and package2 in android" -- what do you mean by this? Do you mean you have two separate modules in an Android Studio project? That is what your related issue is about. "I want to have some kind of check to detect such files and throw a warning/error at compilation time" -- write a custom Lint rule, or see if somebody already wrote one.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, i meant I have two separate modules. I am new to android and not sure how can i write a lint rule for the same, can you help me with some examples?
Couldn't find a pre-existing rule for the same.